# How does one display a collection list filtered by customer tags in shopify using `assign collection =`

Tags: variables, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create a section within the '*Simple*' Shopify theme that filters collections based on customer tags. For example, the customer has the following tags "Foo", "Bar". In turn display the following collections "Foo", "Bar".

I'm not too familiar with liquid so I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible. As such I have duplicated the collection-list.liquid from the '*Simple Theme*' for my base and made the following edits to the file.

**My Edits**

```
  <!-- the magic -->
  <div class="collection-grid">
    <div class="grid grid--uniform">
      
        {% for tag in customer.tags %} // check customer tags.
      
        {% capture tag_handle %} // capture tag URL handle e.g. /t-shirts in a variable 'tag_handle'
            {{ tag | handle }}
        {% endcapture %}
      
          {% unless collection.handle contains tag_handle %} // check collection handles against the current tag handle to find a match. If so then do.

            <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }} slide-up-animation animated" {{ block.shopify_attributes }} role="listitem">
              {% assign collection = collection.handle %} // Assign correct collection. I suspect this to be my stumbling block. See below for reason why.
              {% include 'collection-grid-item' %}
            </div>

          {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %} 

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / the magic -->
```

> With the current code snippet, I do get results equal to the number of customer tags. The problem is that the results are empty, or at least the assigned collection variable is empty.

Any help with this would be **greatly** appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you iterating over multiple collections ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Within the `collection-list.liquid`, there doesn't appear to be a loop so to say; that's looping through the collections group. I suspect the loop is happening elsewhere in the theme. and the result is tweaked within `collection-list.liquid`. I have tried looping through the collections using `{% for collection in collections %}` but it seems to enter an infinite loop within `collection-list.liquid`. or at the very least duplicates the loops.

Comment: Do you want the Admin to select few collections in Shopify customizer and then only display those to user where customer tags match ?

Comment: Not quite, I want to sample all the collections within the system and only display those to a user where the customer tags match.

Comment: @BilalAkbar your question made me stop and think. Thanks for the input. It was greatly appreciated. See my answer if you are interested in my resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have to set up and maintain section blocks, how about something like this?

```
<!-- the magic -->
<div class="collection-grid">
  <div class="grid grid--uniform">
    
    {% for tag in customer.tags %} // for each customer tag do
      {% assign tag_handle = tag | handle %} // get the tag handle (I.e. no spaces & lowercase)

      {% assign collection = collections[tag_handle] %}
      {% if collection == blank %}
        {% continue %}
      {% endif %}

      <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }} slide-up-animation animated" role="listitem">
        {% include 'collection-grid-item' %}
      </div>


    {% endfor %} 
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / the magic -->
```

This approach will:

- Loop through all the customer tags, as before, then
- Takes the handle-ized version of the tag and performs a collection lookup
- Skips to the next tag if there was no matching collection found
- Displays the collection grid item if there is a matching collection

If you are expecting customers to have a lot of tags but only a few collection-related tags, one possible improvement may be to use a special prefix for the collection-related tags that you can check for and skip to the next tag if the prefix is not present.  I also know that Shopify has a limit of 50 uses of the `all_products` lookup per page, but I don't know if there is a similar limit for collection lookups.  Either way, for page performance it is probably best if the number of tags and collection lookups is kept reasonably small.

---

As an aside, one of the things you may be concerned with is page load time.  Having too many expensive Liquid operations can cause Shopify's servers to have a bit of delay when serving your site's pages. While you're trying and testing solutions, one extremely useful tool that you can take advantage of is the "[Shopify Theme Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopify-theme-inspector-f/fndnankcflemoafdeboboehphmiijkgp?hl=en)" plugin for Chrome. This will give you a visual breakdown of how long it takes for Shopify to put your page together on the back-end. *(I have no connection with the plugin at all, it's just a useful tool that I have used a few times when evaluating site performance)*

Comment: Thanks for your input Dave, I had no idea that product look-ups where limited. That's a good fact to learn do you have any reference material for that statement? I can assume at any given time a customer would have 5-10 tags assigned against them. However, most will only need 2-3 tags.

Comment: If it helps I'll explain a little bit of the store flow we're trying to achieve. Basically, each category or 'collection' is equal to a machine. There are many different models of machine. Products are then divided by these collections. We tag the customer with the equipment they own to stop them from being overwhelmed by other machine parts.

Comment: Filtering what is displayed by using customer tags seemed the best way to achieve this.

Comment: The all_products bit is referenced in the "Tip" box on Shopify's "Global Objects" page in the reference: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects#global-objects

It says 20 on that page, but in my experience I've been able to go a bit higher than that - either because the real limit is slightly higher than the stated limit or because I happen to do most of my work with Shopify Plus stores who sometimes have higher limits for various API calls.

Comment: If each customer is only getting 5-10 tags with 2-3 being real collection lookups, it _should_ be fairly efficient to loop through the tag list, treat everything as a potential collection lookup and skip past anything that gives no results.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve my issue by taking a slightly different approach based upon @Bilal Akbar question. Seeing as the existing approach worked in the original `Simple Theme` why try to alter it? Why not allow the admin to load all collections and simply filter the results during the output.

```
<!-- the magic -->
<div class="collection-grid">
  <div class="grid grid--uniform">
    
    {% for tag in customer.tags %} // for each customer tag do
      {% assign tag_handle = tag | handle %} // get the tag handle (I.e. no spaces & lowercase)

      {% for block in section.blocks limit: section.blocks.size %} // keeping the original loop from the original file.
        {% if block.settings.collection == tag_handle %} // check the collections list within the block to see If it matches the tag handle. if so then do.

          <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }} slide-up-animation animated" {{ block.shopify_attributes }} role="listitem">
            {% assign collection = collections[block.settings.collection] %}
            {% include 'collection-grid-item' %}
          </div>

        {% endif %} 
      {% endfor %} 
    {% endfor %} 
    
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / the magic -->
```

Again I'm not too savvy with liquid, If anyone has any alternate or maybe even a better way to achieve my desired result. I would be interested in hearing about it. Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad it works this way...I would have posted the answer earlier.. but the thing is there is no standard way to iterate over all collections in Shopify. All collections are available only on Collections listing page in Shopify...

Comment: You can search on StackOverflow regarding Iterating over collections using Linklist (Menu).

Comment: It's ok, your question really helped me stop and think `was what I was doing necessary?`. r.e. `Linklists` I had tried this approach early on, as I do have a menu that is displaying menu links to collections based on customer tags. Though, I thought to myself "I have the customer tags; I have all the collections, do I really need to include the menus?" I.e. `Linklist`. So I decided against it, as I thought it would be too convoluted. Still +1 for the thought though. :)